# How to define which LESS files are output as .css files

Tags: css, less

I am learning less and im struggling to understand how the output .css files are defined. I am using a sample template that has already got less files defined which are

```
about-section.less
base.less
callout-section.less
mixins.less
responsive.less
styles.less
theme-default.less
```

in visual studio i have defined the following folder structure and dropped all the less files into the less directory so it looks something like this

```
>content
 >>css
 >>less
  >>>about-section.less
  >>>base.less
  >>>callout-section.less
  >>>mixins.less
  >>>responsive.less
  >>>styles.less
  >>>theme-default.less
  >>>header.less
  >>>footer.less
```

To compile the less files i am using something called winless (http://winless.org/) which is just a program that lets you choose a direcorty that contains less files and each time i save in Visual studio all the files get compiled.

Winless state the following

> If you have a folder called 'less' and a folder called 'css' on the
>   same level, add the parent folder. WinLess will then automatically use
>   the css folder as output folder.

When my less files are compiled the css directory is populated with four .css files which are

```
>>css
  >>>mixins.css (contains nothing)
  >>>responsive.css (contains minified css (media queries))
  >>>styles.css (contains minified css)
  >>>theme-default.css (contains nothing)
```

What i dont understand is how do you define which .css files are created as output? i dont require mixins.css, resposive.css or theme-default.css.I just need styles.css because that contains everything.

Why doesnt header.less, footer.less etc output as .css where is it defined that mixins.css, responsive.css, styles.css and theme-default.css are created as .css files?

My styles.less looks as follows

```
@import "mixins.less";
@import "theme-default.less";
@import "base.less";
@import "header.less";
@import "footer.less";
@import "responsive.less";
@import "about-section.less";
@import "callout-section.less";
```

thanks